# Can I directly shift my project to Eclipse Luna from Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project-management, eclipse-juno, eclipse-luna

I am working on a project in eclipse Juno. And I see that Eclipse has a latest version as Luna.
Can I directly Shift my Juno Project to Luna.?
or 
do I have to make some changes.?

Comment: What kind of project is that? Which languages do you use? Which plug-ins do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how large your project is, and how many technologies it uses.

I did this for an enterprise project, and the steps were pretty straightforward:

1. Setup the Luna IDE (i.e. install all necessary software from update sites and such)
2. Copy-paste your Juno workspace (keep the old one)
3. Launch Luna IDE with pasted workspace. Check for any compile errors.

If all is okay, then switch JDK7 to JDK8, and change the workspace compiler to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to import the project in a new workspace with Eclipse Luna, then try to install all the plugins you need and check the project setup so that everything works.

With this way you always can open the old working workspace with Eclipse Juno while you're doing the migration.